# How to modify existing data or create new if doesn't exist in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have created conversation model in mongodb. In collection I want to insert documents and each document must have user1, user2 and array of conversations which I want to insert.

conversationSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
  user1: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  user2: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  conversations : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Conversation', ConversationSchema);
```

messageSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

Now from client side I am going to receive user1 and user2 i.e username which is a string and conversation between the two. Now if there are multiple users say user1, user2, user3, ... then I want to check if conversation exists between any 2 users lets say user1 and user2 if it exists then just $push new message inside conversation else create new conversation and keep on adding messages to existing conversations array. How can I do this in mongodb ?

Comment: at least you must search on internet before direct putting a question here

Comment: @AlokDeshwal I was not aware of `upsert` I searched a lot but couldn't get it.

Comment: i just copy and past your question on google and i found the answer, very first result

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Can you please share the link ?

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Can you please help me here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150727/how-to-insert-and-update-existing-data-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$push and `upsert: true`

If there's no user X and user Y's conversation, it will be upserted. Else, it will $push conversation to existing document.

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
  { user1 : 'X', user2: 'Y' }, 
  { $push : { conversations: ObjectIdOfMessage } },
  { upsert : true},
);
```

Comment: I am populating the Message schema with Conversation schema so do I need to import message schema inside Conversation schema ?

Comment: Ah, if you want to keep current schema, you have to $push ObjectID of conversation.

Comment: If I use the code answered by you then I get an error -> property asignment expected for `upsert`  why so ?

Comment: @fun joker I changed the order by mistake, I updated the answer

Comment: Can you please help me here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150727/how-to-insert-and-update-existing-data-in-mongodb