# How to insert and update existing data in database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created message schema and conversation schema. I am not able to understand why I am not able to store the data inside mongodb.

messageschema.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

conversationschema.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
  user1: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  user2: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  conversations : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Conversation', ConversationSchema);
```

server.js:

```
let db = mongoose.connection;
var user1, user2;

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Database is now connected");

  let io =  socket(server);

io.on("connection", function(socket){
  console.log("Socket Connection Established with ID :"+ socket.id)

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('User Disconnected');
  });

  let chat = db.collection('chat');
  let conversation = db.collection('conversation'); 

      socket.on('GET_USER', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
         user1 = data.user2;
      });

      socket.on('LOGGEDIN_USER', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
         user2 = data.user1;
      });

      socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data){

        let author = data.author;
        let message = data.message;
        let date = data.date;

        // Check for name and message
        if(author !== '' || message !== '' || date !== ''){
            // Insert message
            chat.insert({author:author, message: message, date:date}, function(){
              io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', [data]);
            });

            conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
              { user1 : user1, user2: user2 }, 
              { conversations : { $push : { author, message, date } } },
              { upsert : true}
            );

        }
      });
```

In server.js I want to add messages inside conversation (conversation is an array) and user1 and user2 (user1,user2 are string) inside conversation collection. So if the conversation is not created between user1 and user2 then create new one and store it in collection. If the previous chat is present i.e messages exist in conversation then just push the messages inside conversation array. I have implemented it in above server.js but documents are not getting inserted inside conversation collection. Documents are getting addded only chat collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `findOneAndUpdate` function incorrectly. The second argument is not correct. Please check the mongoDB docs ([`db.collection.findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)) to read how to use it correctly. There, you can find

> **Parameter:** update
>   **Type:** document
>   **Description:** The modifications to apply.
>   Use Update Operators such as `$set`, `$unset`, or `$rename`.
>   Using the update() pattern of field: value for the update parameter throws an error.

```
conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
    { user1 : user1, user2: user2 }, 
    { conversations : { $push : { author, message, date } } }, // <<---- not OK
    { upsert : true}
);
```

You need to use `$set` at the second argument:

```
{ $set: <your object> }
```

Comment: why $set is required ? I just want to push messages from messageschema if the conversations array is not empty. If it is empty then insert the new document i.e message. Note: I am using ref in conversation schema

Comment: @funjoker `$set` is required because `findOneAndUpdate()` requires it as part of its syntax. You want to set the value of a field, so you need to use `$set` in this. As mentioned in the documentation page, other than `$set` you can also have `$unset`, `$rename`, or any other operators in the [update operators list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this below
   **`$push : { conservations : <<jsonObject.>>}`**

Example

```
 conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user1 : user1, user2: user2 }, 
        { $push : {conversations : { author : 'author',message : 'message',date : 'date' }}},
        { upsert : true}
    );
```